# How to link all actions for an object from the other file?

Tags: animation, import, linked-data

I have two blend files: one with the animated model - let's say `model.blend` and all actions (e.g. idle, walk...) and the in the other file, say `scene.blend` I have scene setup with camera, lights, shadow catcher and a script to render all frames in some specific way - the logic is really simple - think render walk animation when rotating an object and also skipping some frames.

All animations in `model.blend` are defined as separate actions in the action editor and all have fake user assigned. I.e. I have one for a T-pose, the other for idle animation, another one for walk animation, etc.

The problem is that linked object that I import via `File > Link` doesn't carry all the actions that I defined for that object, only the one that was selected in the `model.blend` action editor view. So in order to render all separate animations for the object I have to switch to `model.blend`, select another animation in the action editor, save and close `model.blend`, switch to `scene.blend` and render animation again. Is there a better way to achieve that?

To add: when I switch to `Animation > Actions Editor` I don't see all actions via actions drop down, only some of them plus the latest selected animation:

In `model.blend` here is how list of actions are showing up in the action editor's dropdown:

[image: model.blend > Action Editor > Actions Dropdown]

Here is what I see in the scene collection tree, also in `model.blend`:

[image: model.blend > scene collection]

In the above tree I don't understand why I have some actions under `NLA Tracks` but not all of them.

Here is how the object shows up in the `scene.blend`'s scene collection view:

[image: scene.blend > scene collection]

And finally these are the actions I can see in `scene.blend`'s action editor:

[image: scene.blend > Actions Editor]

Choosing any actions except for the active one - in the example above it is `Walk` animation - makes no effect - the active animation (again, the one that was selected in `model.blend` action editor) is the only one I can preview in the action editor.

It feels that I'm not doing something that Blender is designed for - I guess I have to import the object via some sort of an asset and linking an object from the other file won't bring up all animations defined for that object?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood something, but have you tried to link the actions as well?

Comment: I tried via the same `File > Link` - indeed you can import this from the `Actions` section of the model file but then opening any linked action in the recipient file doesn't change object in any way.

Comment: Try linking the object instead of the collection and then linking the rest of the actions.

Comment: That works but only if you imported separate objects instead of a collection. Which by itself carries another limitation: with that type of linking it is not possible to rotate objects

Answer (score 1):

Trying to answer this question myself, I think the best workaround would be to have all actions defined in one sequence and have predefined numbers for when a certain animation starts and when it finishes. I.e. frame 0: t-pose, 1-11: idle animation, frame 12-38 - walk animation, etc.

I now recall seeing an example of blend file someone shared on one forum (unrelated to my question) where it was done exactly in this manner, and while looking weird I now understand that this allows easy linking.

Probably a better solution would be to somehow mark things as assets but I know nothing on to what extent it helps. If someone has a link to documentation or illustration on how to achieve this, I'd be happy to edit this answer / accept yours as a solution to this question.